# How to shuffle the training data set for each epochs while mantaining the intial one?

Tags: python, shuffle

**Perceptron**

I want to compare the training accuracy between shuffling the training dataset and without shuffling the training dataset for each epochs. I have done the part that without shuffling the training dataset, but I have no idea how to implement the code with shuffling into the existing code in order to plot a graph to visualize the difference between training accuracy with shuffling and without shuffling.

```
class Perceptron():
    def __init__(self, num_epochs, num_features, averaged):
        super().__init__()
        self.num_epochs = num_epochs
        self.averaged = averaged
        self.num_features = num_features
        self.weights = None
        self.bias = None

    def init_parameters(self):
        self.weights = np.zeros(self.num_features)
        self.bias = 0

        pass

    def train(self, train_X, train_y, dev_X, dev_y):
        self.init_parameters()

        train_acc = []
        dev_acc = []

        for epoch in range(self.num_epochs):

            preds = []

            for i in range(51775):
                if (safe_sparse_dot(self.weights, train_X[i].T, dense_output = True) + self.bias==0):
                    a=np.array(sample([-1,1],1)).astype('float64')
                else:
                    a = safe_sparse_dot(self.weights, train_X[i].T, dense_output = True) + self.bias 
                y_hat = np.sign(a)
                yhat = preds.append(y_hat)
                if (train_y[i]*a) <=0:
                    self.weights = self.weights+ train_y[i]*train_X[i]
                    self.bias = self.bias + train_y[i]

            arr_ravel = np.array(preds).ravel()
            training_acc = np.mean(arr_ravel==train_y)
            train_acc.append(training_acc)
            development_acc = np.mean(self.predict(dev_X)==dev_y)
            dev_acc.append(development_acc)

    def predict(self, X):
        predicted_labels = []
        for j in X:
            if ((safe_sparse_dot(self.weights, j.T, dense_output = True) + self.bias)==0):
                a=np.array(sample([-1,1],1)).astype('float64')
            else:
                a = safe_sparse_dot(self.weights, j.T, dense_output = True) + self.bias              
            y_hat = np.sign(a)
            predicted_labels.append(y_hat)
        array_ravel = np.array(predicted_labels).ravel()

        return array_ravel
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of shuffling the data, create an index array and shuffle that every epoch. This way you keep the original order.

```
idx = np.arange(train_X.shape[0])
np.random.shuffle(x)
train_X_shuffled = train_X[idx]
train_y_shuffled = train_y[idx]
```

Adding this to your code (making copies of original data, so change the code as little as possible):

```
class Perceptron():
    def __init__(self, num_epochs, num_features, averaged):
        super().__init__()
        self.num_epochs = num_epochs
        self.averaged = averaged
        self.num_features = num_features
        self.weights = None
        self.bias = None

    def init_parameters(self):
        self.weights = np.zeros(self.num_features)
        self.bias = 0

        pass

    def train(self, train_X, train_y, dev_X, dev_y):
        self.init_parameters()

        train_acc = []
        dev_acc = []

        # Make copies of the original data
        train_X_unshuffled = train_X.copy()
        train_y_unshuffled = train_y.copy()
        idx = np.arange(train_X.shape[0])

        for epoch in range(self.num_epochs):
            # Get shuffled dataset
            np.shuffle(idx)
            train_X = train_X_unshuffled[idx]
            train_y = train_y_unshuffled[idx]


            preds = []

            for i in range(51775):
                if (safe_sparse_dot(self.weights, train_X[i].T, dense_output = True) + self.bias==0):
                    a=np.array(sample([-1,1],1)).astype('float64')
                else:
                    a = safe_sparse_dot(self.weights, train_X[i].T, dense_output = True) + self.bias 
                y_hat = np.sign(a)
                yhat = preds.append(y_hat)
                if (train_y[i]*a) <=0:
                    self.weights = self.weights+ train_y[i]*train_X[i]
                    self.bias = self.bias + train_y[i]

            arr_ravel = np.array(preds).ravel()
            training_acc = np.mean(arr_ravel==train_y)
            train_acc.append(training_acc)
            development_acc = np.mean(self.predict(dev_X)==dev_y)
            dev_acc.append(development_acc)

    def predict(self, X):
        predicted_labels = []
        for j in X:
            if ((safe_sparse_dot(self.weights, j.T, dense_output = True) + self.bias)==0):
                a=np.array(sample([-1,1],1)).astype('float64')
            else:
                a = safe_sparse_dot(self.weights, j.T, dense_output = True) + self.bias              
            y_hat = np.sign(a)
            predicted_labels.append(y_hat)
        array_ravel = np.array(predicted_labels).ravel()

        return array_ravel
```

Comment: Thanks of the solution! However, where should I add the code into my existing code?

Comment: I added how it would work in your code, assuming that `train_X` has shape `(n_samples, n_features)` and similar.

Comment: Since I obtain the the training accuracy for unshuffled dataset already, does it means that I need to do another for loop for the shuffle one? Do you implement `train_X_shuffled = train_X[idx]`
`train_y_shuffled = train_y[idx]` in the code or these are not necessary already?

Comment: Get a little bit confused on how to loop through the original (unshuffle) and the shuffle train dataset in order to get the training accuracy for each epochs. Sorry for so many questions, I'm still new to python

Comment: In the above I make a backup of the original arrays, then overwrite `train_X` and `train_y` each epoch. The training accuracy is not something you can really compare, since you seem to change your weights between individual predictions.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, in fact, I need to plot four lines in the same graph which are the training accuracy and development accuracy for the shuffle and unshuffle dataset, to see whether shuffling the data set will make the resukt better or not. Hence, I need to maintain the original (unshuffle) accuracy for taining and development in order to plot the 4 lines graph. In my case, I stored the result of each epochs for training and development accuracy in `train_acc = []` and `dev_acc = []`